# Google Places Autocomplete Api 2019

Tags: java, android

I have been trying for days now and I just can't find a solution for using the Google's places autocomplete API. All the methods that I found were majority of the older version. Now, with the Google Play Services version of the Places SDK for Android (in Google Play Services 16.0.0) being deprecated, I can't seem to find a working updated code. All the solutions I find online are not working for me and I can't even understand what is happening. Can someone just elaborate the code for the new way to use the Google Place Autocomplete API.

This is what I have done till now.

```java
public class SearchAndFilter extends AppCompatActivity {
    String TAG = "placeautocomplete";
    TextView txtView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_and_filter);
        txtView = findViewById(R.id.txtView);

        // Initialize Places.
        Places.initialize(getApplicationContext(), "MY_KEY");
        // Create a new Places client instance.
        PlacesClient placesClient = Places.createClient(this);

        // Initialize the AutocompleteSupportFragment.
        AutocompleteSupportFragment autocompleteFragment = (AutocompleteSupportFragment)
                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.autocomplete_fragment);

        // Specify the types of place data to return.
        autocompleteFragment.setPlaceFields(Arrays.asList(Place.Field.ID, Place.Field.NAME));

        // Set up a PlaceSelectionListener to handle the response.
        autocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {
                // TODO: Get info about the selected place.
                txtView.setText(place.getName()+","+place.getId());
                Log.i(TAG, "Place: " + place.getName() + ", " + place.getId());
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Status status) {
                // TODO: Handle the error.
                Log.i(TAG, "An error occurred: " + status);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Layout File

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activity.SearchAndFilter">
    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/idCardView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

        <fragment android:id="@+id/autocomplete_fragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:name="com.google.android.libraries.places.widget.AutocompleteSupportFragment"
            />

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

When I run the above code, the search bars comes with the google watermark, but just as I type in something, the bar just closes. I have no idea why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just call this function in Oncreate();

```
    /**
 * Sets up the autocomplete fragment to show place details when a place is selected.
 */
private void setupAutoCompleteFragment() {
    PlaceAutocompleteFragment autocompleteFragment = (PlaceAutocompleteFragment)
            getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.place_autocomplete_fragment);

    AutocompleteFilter typeFilter = new AutocompleteFilter.Builder()
            .setTypeFilter(Place.TYPE_COUNTRY).setCountry("IN")

            .build();
    autocompleteFragment.setFilter(typeFilter);

    autocompleteFragment.setHint(getResources().getString(R.string.search_stadium_court_area));
    autocompleteFragment.searchIcon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    autocompleteFragment.input.setTextSize(10f);

    autocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {


        @Override
        public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {
            showPlace(getString(R.string.place_autocomplete_search_hint), place);

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Status status) {
            showResponse("An error occurred: " + status);
        }
    });
}


    private void showPlace(String source, Place place) {
    locationSelect = AppConstants.LOCATION_SELECTED_ONITEMCLICK;

    PlaceBean placeBean = new PlaceBean();


    placeBean.setAddress(String.valueOf(place.getAddress()));
    placeBean.setLatitude(String.valueOf(place.getLatLng().latitude));
    placeBean.setLongitude(String.valueOf(place.getLatLng().longitude));
    placeBean.setName((String) place.getName());
    placeBean.setCityname(cityName);

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtra("location", placeBean);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
    finish();

}
```

Comment: Am I missing on some dependency? Because PlaceAutocompleteFragment, setLatitude, setAddress, setLongitude etc can not be resolved and giving error. I have included this already implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:1.1.0'.

Comment: try this  dependency      implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places-compat:1.0.0'

Comment: Tried, it didn't work. place_autocomplete_fragment, TYPE_COUNTRY, search_stadium_court_area, searchIcon, input, showResponse can't be resolved.

Comment: So i was doing my research, and I found out the the api key that I generate has to be a billing enabled one. Will it not work if its not billed?

Answer (score 0):

Search Bar close reason is this error

> Status{statusCode=PLACES_API_ACCESS_NOT_CONFIGURED, resolution=null}

Follow this tapes

> Add the Gradle Dependancy

```
implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:1.0.0'
```

> Initialize the Place API

```
Places.initialize(getApplicationContext(), "YOUR_API_KEY");
```

> Start the Autocomplete Intent

```
List<Place.Field> fields = Arrays.asList(Place.Field.ID, Place.Field.NAME);
    Intent intent = new Autocomplete.IntentBuilder(
            AutocompleteActivityMode.OVERLAY, fields)
            .build(this);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1101);
```

> onActivityResult

```
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == request_code) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Place place = Autocomplete.getPlaceFromIntent(data);
            Log.i(TAG, "ManishPlace: " + place.getName() + ", " + place.getId());
            txt_search.setText(place.getName());
        } else if (resultCode == AutocompleteActivity.RESULT_ERROR) {
            // TODO: Handle the error.
            Status status = Autocomplete.getStatusFromIntent(data);
            Log.i(TAG, status.getStatusMessage());
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // The user canceled the operation.
        }
    }
}
```

> Or use this GitHub example created by me [Master-Google-Place-API](https://github.com/ManishAndroidIos/Master-Google-Place-API)

Comment: The above part of the whole code that is given on the github link is just for the search autocomplete part?

Comment: @RohanVaish yes it is, Place place = Autocomplete.getPlaceFromIntent(data); using this you can extract any thing Log.i(TAG, "ManishPlace: " + place.getName() + ", " + place.getId());

Comment: Okaay. so I was implementing this method and I get this error, Duplicate class com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture found in modules guava-23.5-android.jar (com.google.guava:guava:23.5-android) and listenablefuture-1.0.jar (com.google.guava:listenablefuture:1.0), What on earth is this?

Comment: try this in gradle file bellow apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
  
  com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin.config.disableVersionCheck = true

Comment: there is no apply plugin:'com.google.gms.google-services'

Comment: how can you use any firebase service without plugin:'com.google.gms.google-services'  add this line in build.gradle app module

Comment: It gives me this error Plugin with id 'com.google.gms.google-services' not found.

Comment: It's Solved. Thanks. You helped a lot

Comment: I used the method given above by @Hitesh Khushwa. I was making mistakes in the dependencies in which you helped me . :)